# ASP.NET MVC Controller Authorization Best Practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Which of the following solutions is considered a best-practice for controller authorization (notice the placement of `AllowAnonymous` and `Authorize` attributes). Do either of these approaches have any advantages/disadvantages over the other, or is this simply a moot point?

### Solution 1

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

```
[Authorize]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to mix anonymous and authenticated controller actions in the same controller I would opt for #2. If you forget to add the `[AllowAnonymous]` you'll notice it pretty quick.

On the other hand if you forget to add the `[Authorize]` in #1 you could potentially open a controller action to the public that shouldn't be.

Having said that, I'd separate the authorized portion of the site from the anonymous in different controllers (or areas if the site is large enough). In my opinion mixing the two in the same controller and then relying on developers to remember to put an attribute on the methods that are the exception to the rule is, in the long run, just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Craig. I would usually add the following code to my global

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        //Add this so all controllers need Authorization
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

To ensure all my controllers require Authorize